# Control the sound of an NFC reader

Tags: python, nfc

I am using pynfc to read in NFC tags. I have an ACR 122U USB NFC reader/writes unit. This unit is capable to make a sound when it reads in a tag, however i was unable to find anything in the pynfc docs about controlling it. Is there a way with either pynfc, or some other python, or linux OS to invoke the sound of an NFC reader?

Comment: The [API documentation](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.04.pdf) for that device lists a couple of commands to control the "buzzer" (sections 6.2 and 6.7 of said docs). Have you tried sending those commands?

Comment: @JonahBishop Thanks, it seems like a good start, but i dont know how can i control the reader this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `nfcpy` i found out that if the `on-connect` function returns `True` the buzzer and the light will go off if the reader is capable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import nfc
import time
import datetime

def on_connect(tag):
    print('Last read: {}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    return True

while True:
    with nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb') as clf:
        clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': on_connect, 'beep-on-connect': True})
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to buzz the buzzer:
Add the following code to `pynfc/__init__.py` at line 75.(above def poll at same indent)

```
def buzz(self):
    ba = (c_ubyte * 9)(*[0xFF,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x4C,0x10,0x00,0x01,0x01])
    result = nfc.nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes.argtypes[3]._type_()
    nfc.nfc_initiator_transceive_bytes(self.pdevice, ctypes.byref(ba), len(ba), ctypre.byref(result),2,1000)
```

Call nfc.buzz() from your script.

I do not have a device to test the code.  Also note that you cannot poll and buzz at the same time.